# Why does the equation of the circumference of a circle in spherical and hyperbolic space satisfy $C''=-KC$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, circles, curvature, pi

In a space of constant curvature $K$, the function for $C(r)$ where $C$ is the circumference of a circle of radius $r$ satisfies:

$C''=−KC$, with initial conditions $C(0)=0$ and $C'(0)=2\pi$.

(Units check: Gaussian curvature $K$ is units $1/\rm length^2$, $C$ is units $\rm length$, and $C''$ is units $1/\rm length$.)

When $K=0$, as in flat space, this gives us the familiar $C=2\pi r$ that we all know and love. When $K>0$ this gives us $C=2\pi\frac{\sin(r\sqrt K)}{\sqrt K}$, and when $K<0$ this gives us $C=2\pi\frac{\sinh (r\sqrt{-K})}{\sqrt{-K}}$.

**Is there an intuitive reason why $C''=-KC$ holds?** In other words, is there an intuitive reason why $C''/C$ is constant in surfaces of constant curvature? (The initial conditions $C(0)=0$ and $C'(0)=2\pi$ are, I think, pretty intuitive.)

I think the explanation lies in Jacobi fields, but I forget the details of how those work.

We can frame the question in a different way. Given a point $p$ and *any* function $C$, we can "grow" a manifold around $p$ such that $C$ is the circumference of circles of radius $r$ around $p$. This gives us a whole family of manifolds, including for example the paraboloid, but the resulting manifold only looks the same at every point when $C''/C$ is constant. (You can make circles grow like $C$ from a given point, but unless $C''/C$ is constant, you'll have trouble making them grow like that from *every* point.) Why?

Comment: Side note: I feel like the fact that Gaussian curvature is units ${\rm length}^{-2}$ isn't talked about enough. The formula for the area of a triangle, $KA=\alpha+\beta+\gamma-\pi$ makes a lot of sense now (and is valid for $K=0$!). Similarly, holonomy says walking (parallel transporting) around a region of area $A$ leaves you rotated by $AK$.

Comment: Also, in a sense, $C/2r$ is "pi" in a surface of constant curvature $K$! You'll just have to get used to pi being a (nonconstant) function, not a constant. Happy pi day!

Comment: Hm hm hm actually maybe holonomy is the key here. If $A(r)$ is the area of a circle of radius $r$ then $A'=C$, and this is the same as $C'=-KA$. In other words, $C'$ is negative the holonomy. That seems like something that could have an intuitive justification.

Comment: I meant $C'=-KA+2\pi$, surely.